next.js client app with rewrites build with HTML and js
I have a pure client app. It's an app migrated from deprecated create-react-app. API calls use rewrites. I made it work in my local env and want to see how it works when deployed.
How to build this app to get index.html, js file(s), and CSS? I can't use output: 'export', because of rewrites. Default build serves files that can't be easily deployed (no index.html, just a bunch of js files in three folders)
